# Error on filename creating Ifstream object

Tags: c++, ifstream

Any particular reason why this would fail?

```
    std::string r = "Hej.whatever";
    std::string const *p = &r;
    std::ifstream file ((*p).c_str(), std::ios::in, std::ios::ate);
    std::ifstream file ((*p), std::ios::in, std::ios::ate);
```

```
error: no matching function for call to
  ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const string&,
               const openmode&, const openmode&)’
  std::ifstream file ((*p), std::ios::in, std::ios::ate);
```

Comment: What use is the pointer?

Comment: Thought maybe it would solve the problem passing the filename as a pointer. I know its irrelevant because it produced the same error if the filename is just typed there instead. $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0 Thanks

Comment: Hey Some programmer dude, I read your mud code its pretty good!

Comment: Thank you! :) But it's also oh so old, and incomplete. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass several modes by bitwise OR(`|`):

```
std::ifstream file ((*p), std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
std::ifstream file2 ((*p), std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
```

and you can remove `.c_str()` from first call, there is no need in it

Comment: @Moonrak Not at all! Good luck!